# MPI Hangs at Recv for Specific Input

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi

I'm a newbie when it comes to MPI and I have no idea why my program hangs.

My programs opens a file and receives a size N, it then uses N to read in a NxN 2D array.
I then send general info to each processor and then split the array horizontally into chunks and send it each processor.

```
int size, 
int N = -1, generations = -1, sliceSize;
MPI_Status Stat;
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);



if(rank==0){
std::fstream file;
file.open(argv[1]);

file >> N;

std::vector<std::vector<int>> grid(N, std::vector<int>(N));
sliceSize = N / size;

//read in matrix board from file
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        std::string temp;
        file >> temp;
        for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
            grid[i][j] = temp[j] - '0';
        }
    }
    file.close();

// send general info to each processor including 0;
int info[2];
        info[0] = N;
        info[1] = sliceSize;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            MPI_Send(&info, 3, MPI_INT, i, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }

//Split grid and send to each processor including 0;
/*
Examples Split
00000
00000

00000
00000
*/
for (int z = 0; z < size; ++z) {
            int slice[sliceSize][N];
            for (int i = 0; i < sliceSize; ++i) {
                for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
                    slice[i][j] = grid[i + (z * sliceSize)][j];
                }
            }
            MPI_Send(&(slice[0][0]), N * sliceSize, MPI_INT, z, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }

}

//All ranks to execute this
 int localInfo[2];        // local info for initial information

    std::cout << "Here1 " << rank << std::endl;
    MPI_Recv(&localInfo, 4, MPI_INT, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &Stat);
    std::cout << "Here2 " << rank << std::endl;
    N = localInfo[0];
    sliceSize = localInfo[1];
    generations = localInfo[2];

    int mySlice[sliceSize][N];
    std::cout << "Here3 " << rank << std::endl;
    MPI_Recv(&(mySlice[0][0]), sliceSize * N, MPI_INT, 0, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &Stat);
    std::cout << "Here4 " << rank << std::endl;

//Do stuff with mySlice
```

I used print statements to try and help filter out issue.
The funny thing is that it works fine when N=10 or N=20 but any larger and the issue occurs.

Example input:

```
30
001000000000000000000000000000
101000000000000000000000000000
011000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000
```

When running the code with the above input using 2 processors with:
 `mpirun -oversubscribe -np 2 ./Parallel 40x40Input.txt`

My output:

```
Here1 1
Here2 1
Here3 1
```

I think the issue is with the second MPI_Recv call but I just can't figure out why.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: `MPI_Send` is strictly speaking a blocking call, so your first send loop will cause a deadlock on process zero. Or it may not, but you can't count on that. Please improve your design. You should probably use a scatter. Your code is also hard to read because the indentation is a mess. Please use an editor like emacs that helps you with indentation.

Comment: Thank you I'm trying to change it to a scatter. My new plan is to read the matrix as a N*N sized 1D array and scatter it, however I'm a bit confused, since the file is only open at rank 0 and the grid is only initialized at rank 0 how do i scatter it? Since it cannot be in the if(rank==0) branch.

Comment: After changing it to use MPI_Scatter() [Link](https://pastebin.com/7K1eZsZ0) I ran into segmentation faults on certain processors when trying to run it with 5 processors.

Comment: Your first scatter should be a broadcast.